# How can I make a UI element in Windows trigger another UI element?

Tags: user-interface, events, windows-10, autohotkey

Specifically, what I want to accomplish is:

a.) When I click the Start button, I would like to have Windows also show the Desktop in addition to bringing up the Start Menu.

b.) When I click the "Show Desktop" button, I would like to have Windows also bring up the Start Menu in addition to showing the Desktop.

c.) When I press the Windows key on my keyboard, I would like it to both bring up the Start Menu and show the Desktop.

At the moment, I only know how to do c, and that with AutoHotkey. I am not averse to solving each of my 3 goals with separate scripts/programs, but it will be all the nicer if I can do it with one.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: if you want to do this with simple ahk, you can make use of `#ifwinactive` and `LButton::` Hotkey. might work

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, I'll just explain how this can be done in AutoHotkey.

a) Using [SetTimer](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) and [MouseGetPos](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) you can set a subroutine to check if the mouse is on the coordinates of your Start Button and than have a routine that if Left Mouse is pressed while mouse is on those coordinates Send WindowsKey + D (show desktop).

b) Use the same technique as above... except have it Send Windows Key on Left Mouse button down.

c) You solved this yourself...